# Local and remote (NAS) file matching permissions

Tags: 18.04, permissions, ldap, nas

I have a Synology NAS (DS214play) where all my multimedia files and others are stored.  However, because I make changes to files from either the client running Ubuntu 18.04 or the NAS, I run into permission issues and I would like to find a solution to this problem.

I think a possible solution is to setup LDAP services in the server and configure my client.  I'm familiar with Microsoft's Active Directory and is the kind of functionality I am after without all the users as it is for me only.

I'm open to any suggestion, the simplest solution wins.